# Visual Studio Code [pylint] E0001:invalid syntax

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code with the `ms-python.python` extension and I get this error in many different files always when I import functions or classes using `from xxxx import xxxx`.

Even if I only have two or three lines of code I get this error.

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validate # <-- error on this line.
from app_two.models import users
```

Comment: You aren't using `from xxxx import xxxx`, you are using invalid syntax, as your error suggests, by doing `from xxxx import xxxx`. Try `import xxxx`

Comment: Please don't include images of code. Just enter the code in the question . You can format the code by highlighting what you want formatting and clicking the `{}` button. I appreciate it wont show the squiggly red line but you can just add a comment instead saying `# <- error here` or something similar.

Comment: `from django.core import` is an incomplete statement. You only use `from x import y` when you want to import a specific thing (or set of things) from the module. If you just want to import the whole module, you use `import x`. You can import everything into the default namespace using `from x import *`, but its a bad practice, as it can introduce a lot of stuff into that namespace and cause you problems down the line.

Comment: @PaulRooney thanks I am pretty new in stack overflow thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you linked (and not your edit); you aren't using `from xxxx import xxxx`. You are using invalid syntax, as your error suggests, by doing `from xxxx import`, which is invalid.

Instead of;

```
from django.core import
```

You should try:

```
from django import core
```